# How to create custom docker Image for Alfresco 6.2 with any custom/addon amp files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I am trying to create custom docker image for Alfresco 6.2, I already did the set-up for Alfresco 6.2 docker container and it's up and running fine.
Now I have to create custom docker image by adding/installing following amp files in the custom image.

```
alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-repo-2.1.x.amp
alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-share-2.1.x.amp
```

Can someone please share the exact steps to generate custom docker images?

I have following commands in my Fockerfile

```
FROM alfresco/alfresco-content-repository-community:6.2.0-ga
ARG TOMCAT_DIR=/usr/local/tomcat \
ADD alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-repo-2.1.x.amp ${TOMCAT_DIR}/amps
RUN java -jar ${TOMCAT_DIR}/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install \ ${TOMCAT_DIR}/amps ${TOMCAT_DIR}/webapps/alfresco --nobackup
```

And I am getting following error after executing command:-
***docker build -t customacs/acs-platform .***

```
05290000 An IO error was encountered during deployment of the AMP into the WAR
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: All this is well documented. You may want to search for `Dockerfile` and `docker build`.

Comment: @Henry There are the steps to create custom docker images, but I have specifically mentioned in Alfresco 6.2 with custom amps, I already tried multiple ways, but getting some issues. So I am expecting that from alfresco background did this, then he will provide the exact steps. I will post error logs in below comment for your reference.

Comment: @Henry I am getting following error while creating custom docker image. 05290000 An IO error was encountered during deployment of the AMP into the WAR
The command '/bin/sh -c java -jar ${TOMCAT_DIR}/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install \ ${TOMCAT_DIR}/amps ${TOMCAT_DIR}/webapps/alfresco --force' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Can you show us your Dockerfile? This might be a permission issue.

Comment: @Henry I have updated question body with Dockerfile commands, Please have a look and let me know if you fill anything is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use the root user to build the docker file.

Docker file for repo amp:

```
FROM alfresco/alfresco-content-repository-community:6.2.0-ga

USER root

COPY ./amps/alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-repo-2.1.x.amp /usr/local/tomcat/amps/

RUN java -jar /usr/local/tomcat/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install /usr/local/tomcat/amps /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco -directory -nobackup -force \
 && chown -R root:Alfresco /usr/local/tomcat

USER alfresco
```

Docker file for share amp :

```
FROM alfresco/alfresco-share:6.2.0

COPY ./amps/alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-share-2.1.x.amp /usr/local/tomcat/amps_share/

RUN java -jar /usr/local/tomcat/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install /usr/local/tomcat/amps_share /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/share -directory -nobackup -force \
```

I have faced a similar issue but not the same.

Error Message: 08160000 An IO error was encountered during deployment of the AMP into the WAR

The most likely reason for this error is due to lack of permission to update the war or files in the webapp.  You may run the MMT utility with the '-verbose' flag to find out what file/directory is being updated right before the exception is thrown.  That resource is typically the reason for the error.

Answer (score -1):

Share Connector is for Enterprise only. It looks like you are trying to install it on the Community Edition stack:

```
FROM alfresco/alfresco-content-repository-community:6.2.0-ga
```

Cheers,

Eddie

Comment: I tried with Enterprise version as well, but getting same error.